# How to change review list pagination default value

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

[image]

> I have display review list on my product page and also display
>   pagination but how can i change default pagination value 10,20,50.
>   using admin setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you're looking for is:

/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Pager.php

The line you want to modify to adjust review pagination limits is this one:

```
protected $_availableLimit = array(10=>10,20=>20,50=>50);
```

Replace the numbers with the review page limits that you'd prefer.

Of course, since this change is in core code, you'll first want to copy this file into /app/code/local/Mage/Page/Block/Html, and then make your change, to ensure that upgrades do not override it.